# Why Can't Data from Kendo DataSource's Observable Object Be Logged to Console?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to read from a remote service. When I use the `.read()` method, I can see the AJAX response on my browser's `Network` tab, but I don't understand why I can't log the the server's response to my browser's console.

Here's my code:

```
var accountsListDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8085/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.office.web.services.AccountsService",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    op: "list"
                },
                success: function(){
                    console.log("DataSource Read Success");
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("DataSource Read Failed");
                }
            });
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(response) {
                return response;
            }
        }
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) {
         var response = e.response;
         console.log(response);        
    }
});
```

I manually ran `accountsListDs.read()` from my browser's console. I get a perfect response from the server. When I tried to do `accountsListDs.data()`, it returns an empty array. I suppose, it makes an async call, so `.data()` won't immediately work, I even tried to hook it up with `requestEnd` event (As described in Kendo's overly helpful documentation, but still no luck).

Even if I copy paste the code from Kendo's documentation, it does not work.

What am I missing here?

[image]

(Thanks in advance, CodingWithSpike)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you are not propagating the data received by the `ajax` request. You should invoke `op.success` with the received data:

```
var accountsListDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(op) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8085/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.office.web.services.AccountsService",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    op: "list"
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("DataSource Read Success");
                    op.success(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("DataSource Read Failed");
                }
            });
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(response) {
                return response;
            }
        }
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) {
         var response = e.response;
         console.log(response);        
    }
});
```

The following code snippet shows a running version of the idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read:  function (op) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(data){
            console.log("DataSource Read Success");
            op.success(data);
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log("DataSource Read Failed");
          }
        });
      }
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) {
      var response = e.response;
      console.log(response);
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    schema: {
      data: function(response) {
        return response;
      }
    }
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
      { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 }
    ],
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Your code perfectly runs. I just replaced the url and sent data parameters (also switched from jsonp to json), and now I get this error.

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Gqm14tQ.png

Comment: You can use JSON as far as you are running it in the same server otherwise you will have CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) problems.
What you show doesn't seem to be an array of values. Basically the Data needs to be an array and you are showing a `status` and something called `providerAccounts` that is shown just as `Object`. Where is the returned data? What do you see if you display the received data in the `success` function of the `ajax` call?

Comment: No, the issue isn't cross domain restrictions. Success callback returns this:

{"status":"SUCCESS","providerAccounts":{"autoLogin":[],"online":[]}}

Comment: I found out my mistake. I need to parse the server response before I can use it with Kendo DataSource. I'll accept your solution as an answer.